# Installshield 2011 - crashes at build between "Embedding manifest" and signing

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, installshield, installshield-2011

Since upgrading to a windows 8 & 8.1 machine all my InstallShield projects began failing at signing.  The error occurs after or during the embedding manifest into setup.exe, with the following error:

> Exception ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at address 0x76b34db0 trying to read
>   address 0x00000001.
>
> File           : C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\InstallShield\2011\System\isdev.exe Version        : 17.0.0.714
>   Exception      : c0000005 Address        : 76b34db0 Access Type    :
>   read Access Address : 00000001
>
> ...

When I opted to debug after the crash, I then get an exception in visual studio saying error occurred in Wintrust.dll:

> Unhandled exception at 0x76B34DB0 (wintrust.dll) in isdev.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001.

The error message in the build log ends with:

> ISDEV : error -7132: An error occurred streaming ISSetup.dll support
>   file S:\InstallShields\Server Fix Pack_IS2011\Setup.inx Embedding
>   manifest SetupExe.Admin.manifest into setup.exe Started signing
>   8F8D.tmp ... Successfully signed: 8F8D.tmp

To work around it in smaller projects I removed all signing options, particularly the use of spc and pvk certificate/private key files.

After building the install successfully without signing. I reintroduced signing using just a pfx certificate file. But I can't ever select the option to "sign files in package".

There are some projects where none of these steps work. Has anyone encountered these issues with Windows 8/8.1? Are there any workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: I've had similar issues - signing my setup.exe launcher for my MSI-based installation fails.  I've just learnt to live with it but I have a small bit of shame every time I see someone run the installer and the warning UAC box appears rather than the friendly one with my certificate details.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue, an access violation in **isdev.exe**. I turned off all the signing like you mentioned, rebuilt it and it worked. I turned back on the signing and that now works.

For reference, I'm using a **pfx certificate file** and *Sign Files in Package* is **no**.

**Thank you for your help!!!**

*Side Note:* Make sure you have the certificate registered on your machine, that *might* have something to do with it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem this way:

Just sign as normal, except installer package. Then add this line in post build event:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2011\System\Signtool.exe" sign /f "<private Cert File>.pfx" /p <password> /du "http://<whatever>" /t "<timestamp server. See your cert supplier>" "%<ISReleasePath>%\<Name>.msi"
```

Now everything is signed and the UAC works, too.